# Expected variable to be one of these types: double Instead its type was embedded.fi

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink, fixed-point, zynq

I converted my code from floating to fixed point using fixed point toolbox, but when I pass the variables to complex bandpass decimator block in Simulink, it gives me an error which says that block was expecting data type single or double but instead it is embedded.fi. I don't know how to solve this issue. plz if anyone knows how to solve it,
Thanks
Regards

Comment: Some functions do not support fixed point execution, which function is giving you that error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). so people can better help you with your problem.